# Countour integral $\int {{{(\overline z )}^2}dz} $

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Evaluate $\int {{{(\overline z )}^2}dz} $ along the straight line segment from $z=0$ to $z=2+i$.

My attempt to this question is I change z into $x+iy$ and do the integration;
$$\int_0^{2 + jy} {(x -yi)(x -yi)} dz$$
So, my question is how to do integration with respect to z?

Comment: In mathematics is way more common to denote $\;i=\sqrt{-1}\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc seems like he does mechanical engineering, where this sign seems common.

Comment: yeah in my university we use j instead of i

Comment: @ADG Most probably. This can cause some confusion in a *mathematics site*, though. But it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that:
$$z=0\to2+i\implies z(t)=(2+i)t\quad t\in[0,1],t\in\mathbb R\\\int\bar z^2dz=\int_0^1 \overline{(2+i)}^2t^2(2+i)dt=(2-i)^2(2+i)/3=5(2-i)/3=10/3-5i/3$$

Comment: why we need to intergrate from 0 to 1

Comment: @razercreed since i parametrized it in terms of t and $z(1)=2+i$ and $z(0)=0$ ,since you're going from $z(0)$ to $z(1)$; t goes from 0 to 1

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the parametrization $z(t) = 2t + it$ where $0 \leq t \leq 1$.